# Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting, substring, charindex

I have two T-SQL queries that use `Substring` and `Charindex` to parse text in a `nvarchar` column. They execute by themselves but when I try to union them, I get:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I thought this might be because a `datetime` cast error, so I removed the cast statement from this code:

```
CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ActivityDetail, CAST((CHARINDEX('Date/Time:', ActivityDetail) + 11) AS INT), 10), SUBSTRING(ActivityDetail, CAST((CHARINDEX('Date/Time:', ActivityDetail) + 23) AS INT), 9)) AS DATETIME) AS 'Start Time'
```

I ran the query again and got this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

I **do not** have a `CAST` statement that tries to convert from `varchar` to `bigint` in my code.

I **do** have a window function that uses the created `datetime` column to assign row numbers so that I can filter for rn=1, which is the most recent result.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UnitId] ORDER BY [Start Time] DESC, UnitID DESC) AS rn
```

What am I doing wrong?

Can provide more code but most of it looks like this:

```
CASE 
WHEN SUBSTRING([ActivityDetail],cast((CHARINDEX('Laser A BkGnd Brightness',[ActivityDetail]) - 15) as int),1) = '1' THEN SUBSTRING([ActivityDetail],cast((CHARINDEX('Laser A BkGnd Brightness',[ActivityDetail]) - 15) as int),3)
ELSE SUBSTRING([ActivityDetail],cast((CHARINDEX('Laser A BkGnd Brightness',[ActivityDetail]) - 14) as int),2)
END as 'Laser A Background Brightness'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched for second error after posting. Had to do with order of the columns in the two queries.

Had one query with:

```
SELECT *, rn FROM
```

And the other with:

```
SELECT rn, * FROM
```